# How to get the price using soup in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the proce of an item from the following html.

This is the src

```
 <span class="crwActualPrice">
        <span style="text-decoration: inherit; white-space: nowrap;">
            <span class="currencyINR">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </span>
            <span class="currencyINRFallback" style="display:none">
                Rs. 
            </span>
            13,990.00
        </span>
    </span>
```

This is the code that i tried

```
    dprice = each_result.find_all("span", class_="crwActualPrice")
        for each_price in dprice:
            money_str = each_price.string
            print(money_str)
```

I want to get the value 13990 in `money_str` using python soup.

Comment: What type of objects are `each_result` and `each_price`?

Answer (score 0):

With `soup.select` function:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_data = '''<span class="crwActualPrice">
        <span style="text-decoration: inherit; white-space: nowrap;">
            <span class="currencyINR">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </span>
            <span class="currencyINRFallback" style="display:none">
                Rs. 
            </span>
            13,990.00
        </span>
    </span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')
for curr in soup.select("span.crwActualPrice span.currencyINRFallback"):
    price = curr.nextSibling.strip()
    print(price)
```

prints:

```
13,990.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the content outside of a div using `text()`

```
...
dprice = each_result.find_all("span", class_="crwActualPrice")
for each_price in dprice:
    money_str += reach_price.text()
print(money_str.strip('&nbsp;'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Though i am not 100% about edge cases due to the limited set of data

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
In [2]: s = BeautifulSoup(''' <span class="crwActualPrice">
    ...:         <span style="text-decoration: inherit; white-space: nowrap;">
    ...:             <span class="currencyINR">
    ...:                 &nbsp;&nbsp;
    ...:             </span>
    ...:             <span class="currencyINRFallback" style="display:none">
    ...:                 Rs.
    ...:             </span>
    ...:             13,990.00
    ...:         </span>
    ...:     </span>''')

In [3]: for each in s.select('span.crwActualPrice'):
   ...:     print(each.get_text().strip().replace(' ','').replace('\n', ''))
```